# Make tag synonym for "словники"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Subj, [українські-словники](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%96-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8) must be a synonym for [словники](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Comment: Done. Відразу інше впало у вічі: чому в нас [tag:рід] синонім до [tag:фемінітиви]? Це нормально? (адже, здається, можуть бути питання про рід і не стосовні безпосередньо фемінітивів, наприклад, чоловічий-vs-середній, що таке спільний і т.ін.)

Comment: @Sasha, не знаю, чому синонім. Може, наслідки невдалого ланцюга перейменувань. До «фемінітиви», можливо, варто ще додати англ синонім. P.S. На запитання краще, можливо, надавати відповіді, щоб вони були accepted, і щоб запитання не валялося у списку [unanswered](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered).

Comment: Наскільки я знаю, воно не дасть створити коротку відповідь з одного лише слова «Done» (така відповідь буде автоматично перетворена на коментар). По-моємо, простіше видалити запитання. Але якщо наполягаєте, можу створити відповідь вигляду «Done. <Якась маячня тут, щоби воно не видаляло відповідь>».

Comment: @Sasha чого це видалити? Зрушене слушне (сподіваюся) запитання, навіть існує відповідний теґ, та і взагалі це показник активності сайту, <s>а не то шо січас, коли останній допис — про призначення Модераторів</s> :)

Comment: ok.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done..........................

Comment: Але не обʼєднали наявні? https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4684/8